# Time to burninate [small-electronics]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-blacklist-request

There has been a tag [small-electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/small-electronics) on this site, and I have no idea what it means. Is there such a thing as small and big electronics? I suggest to delete the tag [small-electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/small-electronics)

Comment: ...what *does* that mean?

Comment: This is done, small-electronics tags cannot be created anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a need for this tag and I don't see a need for the tag, it doesn't follow the recommendation on tags because [it's to 'meta'.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)  If nobody else has a problem with removal, remove the tags from each question and I'll delete it.

Edit:

The tag has be blacklisted

Answer (score 8):

Currently (as of 2021-01-03) there are 174 questions tagged [small-electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/small-electronics), and based on the upvotes, number of answers, and general quality of the questions and answers, it seems there is some good content there -- but even with 4 tag watchers, there really isn't any clear meaning to what makes these questions "small electronics". In many cases, the questions and answers would still be useful and could be found without the "small electronics" tag, but there are a few questions that would be left untagged.

I ran a SE data query to find questions that have no other tags besides "small-electronics" (link below); so before we delete the tag [small-electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/small-electronics), we should examine each of these (9) remaining questions and either retag or close/delete these questions, otherwise they will become untagged. Some of these questions have accepted answers, multiple answers, upvotes, bookmarks (favorite), so there's some value worth saving.

We should try to retag only a few at a time, to avoid spamming the "active questions" page -- retagging a question bumps it up to the front of the list, and it doesn't take very much retagging activity to drown out actual new questions.

As of 2021-01-04, these are the questions that have only the single tag [small-electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/small-electronics):

| Question | Date Created | Date Closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Learning electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/405948) | 2018-11-09 20:52:11 | closed 2018-11-10 05:47:15 |
| [Where do I start to look for an automatic off feature on a circuit? (Guidance)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/444119) | 2019-06-18 03:18:23 | closed 2019-06-18 11:10:52 |
| [Single pulse when circuit is powered on](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/451894) | 2019-08-07 04:05:48 | closed 2019-08-13 02:07:42 |

These have been dealt with by adding additional tags:

| Question | Date Created | Date Closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [20V -> 5V -> USB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/490017) | 2020-03-31 00:13:44 | still open |
| [What is a readhead?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/454363) | 2019-08-23 19:44:14 | still open |
| [How should I power a 3V toy motor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/467463) | 2019-11-15 16:47:13 | still open |
| [Endstop switched](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/498327) | 2020-05-08 00:24:33 | still open |
| [What electronic switch should I use?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/510893) | 2020-07-17 12:39:03 | still open |
| [RC timing circuit application](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/528283) | 2020-10-20 07:45:05 | still open |
| [Operational Amplifiers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/422799) | 2019-02-17 14:42:30 | still open |
| [3mm and 5mm LED](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/440951) | 2019-05-29 14:20:54 | still open |

For reference, the query is here (originally from user Passerby):

https://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/query/372728/find-questions-with-a-single-tag-now-case-insensitive?Tag=small-electronics

```
Declare @Tags nvarchar(150)
Set @Tags='<##Tag##>'
Set @Tags = Lower(@Tags)

Select Top 5000 Id As [Post Link], CreationDate, ClosedDate
From Posts
Where Title is not null And Tags=@Tags
Order By CreationDate Desc
```

When there are no longer any questions meeting this criteria, it will then be safe to delete the tag administratively, and blacklist it (I think that requires one of the diamond-moderators).

Comment: I went ahead and added additional tags to "20V -> 5V -> USB" and "What is a readhead?", though I don't have a ton of free time to do all of them now.

Comment: Please let me know by commenting on my question when this process is done, so I can accept this answer.

Comment: That's all of the open ones retagged. The remaining three were closed over a year ago and are unlikely to be salvaged by their original posters. One of the three has no appropriate tag other than [tag:learning] (the question is far too broad), which is probably another pointless tag to remove.

Comment: (of the ones with only the small-electronics tag that is)